# Very basic question, ls a different directory and save file

Tags: directory, ls, filenames

I seriously can't understand where I'm going wrong with his question.  The first part is.

*List all the file and directory names in /etc which have 1 or more numbers in their name. Remember to use "-d" in the ls command, and do not descend into subdirectories (i.e. no recursion). Save this list in caine's home directory as a file called "digit". Do the "ls" command when CDed to /etc, thus your names avoid having "/etc/" stuck in front of them.*

Which is have done with the following command:

```
ls -d *[0-9]* > digit
```

However, the second part of the question is;

*Redo the previous question, except this time repeat the exercise when CDed in /home/caine. Save the output in digit2. "digit" and "digit2" should be identical, except in "digit2" all the filenames will begin "/etc/".*

I thought the following code would work;

```
ls -d ../../etc/ *[0-9]* > digit2
```

When I cat the contents of the file, it appears to have ignored the parameters I have set using the *'s and numbers, I have tried moving the statement around and I am stumped as to why this isn't working.

Any advice, or pref an explanation as to where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.

I know this could be achieved with grep, but even though I've moved on to that and am learning it, I'd still really like to know how I can't get the right syntax for this!

Answer (score 4):

You added an extra space, which split your glob into two separate arguments:

```
ls -d ../../etc/ *[0-9]* > digit2
#               ^ space
```

It should be

```
ls -d /etc/*[0-9]* > digit2
```

No need for the `../..` unless you actually like seeing all those dots in the file.

Comment: Ah thanks, I put the extra dots in because I am CDed into a different directory and thought it would try and look in the current directory for /etc/ rather than go up two levels.

Thanks for pointing out I don't need to space between the input destination and the wildcards

Comment: @Sirus Paths that start with `/` are absolute; it doesn't matter what your current directory is. So `ls etc` is going to look for `etc` in your current directory; `ls /etc` is going to look for the `etc` in the root

Comment: Michael, thank you very much for that input, so if I'm deep in a directory somewhere, and I want to do a ls, I can use absolute paths which will start looking from the top (root) of the directory tree?

Comment: @Sirus Yes absolute paths are written with a leading `/` and by definition start from the root `/`.